# Find pattern in a signal - Variable Frequency and Amplitude

Tags: signal-detection

I assume this question is fairly simple but I haven't been able to find a way yet.

I have a signal that I sample with 256 measures (might be 1024 as well) in live. The signal usually approaches a square like this:
[image]

My goal is to detect when the signal starts to not being square anymore and turns to a "Shark Fin" profile like this:
[image]

Ideally, I would have a function (filter?) that would compare the "Shark Fin" pattern [image] and the measured signal and output a value (in % for example) to express YES or NO the pattent is or isn't contained in the signal (with a certain % of similarity).

The amplitude and the frequency of the signal are variable, which make it impossible to use a Matched Filter (please correct me if I'm wrong). I believe I need to look into Wavelet Transform but I couldn't understand how this works.

Could you explain me how to apply this pattern detection in my signal?
I haven't decided the language or the platform where the algorithm will be executed. The first step is to understand how the algo works.

Thank you for your help.